# Java transform having an object in a different transform appear on a certain position

Tags: java, swing, object, transform

Ok so I have an issue with shots being fired from the player. The shots always appear from  certain place and not in front of the player. I have placed a green square where the shots fires from but of course they should be firing from in this case one of the short sides of the blue rectangle.

I know the issue is caused by the transform. Essentially how the shot object positions is not updated together with the player object. But I simply do not know how to fix the issue.

The commented out code to draw a green triangle inside the players transform essentially will do what I the shot object to do. But I am not sure how to make that happen.

Main/frame class

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
   public static void main(String argvs[]) {
        Board board = new Board();
        board.timer.start();
        Test frame = new Test();
        frame.add(board);
        frame.setTitle("overflow");
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);   
        frame.setResizable(false);      
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Board class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Board extends JComponent implements ActionListener  {
    Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    Player player = new Player();

    Timer timer=new Timer(16, this);

    public Board(){
        //setFocusable(true);
        add(player);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setPaintMode();
        board(g);
        player.draw(g);
        for (int i = player.playerShot.size() - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
            Shot shot = player.playerShot.get(i);
            if(shot.shotX < 0 || shot.shotY < 0 || shot.shotX > size.getWidth() || shot.shotY > size.getHeight())  { 
                player.playerShot.remove(i);
                continue;
            }
            shot.collision();
            shot.draw(g);
        }
    }

    void board(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, (int)size.getWidth(), (int)size.getHeight());
 
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
        if(ev.getSource()==timer){
            player.movement();
            //shot.collision();
          repaint();// this will call at every 1 second
        }
    }
}
```

Player class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Player extends JComponent {
    Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int playerX; // Position of the player
    int playerY;
    private double rotationAngle; // Angle in radians
    public Set<Integer> keysPressed; // Store the keys being pressed
    boolean moving = false;
    ArrayList<Shot> playerShot = new ArrayList<Shot>();



    public Player() {

        playerX = (int) (size.getWidth() / 2); // Initialize player position (you can set your own initial position)
        playerY = (int) (size.getHeight() / 2);
        rotationAngle = 0; 
        keysPressed = new HashSet<>();

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false), "moveForward");
        getActionMap().put("moveForward", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.add(KeyEvent.VK_UP); 
                //movement();            
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true), "forwardStop");
        getActionMap().put("forwardStop", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.remove(KeyEvent.VK_UP);                
                //movement();            
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false), "moveBack");
        getActionMap().put("moveBack", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.add(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);                
               // movement();
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true), "backwardsStop");
        getActionMap().put("backwardsStop", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.remove(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);                
               // movement();
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), "rotateLeft");
        getActionMap().put("rotateLeft", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.add(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);                
                //movement();           
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), "leftRotateStop");
        getActionMap().put("leftRotateStop", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.remove(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);                
                //movement();           
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), "rotateRight");
        getActionMap().put("rotateRight", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.add(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);                
                //movement();            
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "rightRotateStop");
        getActionMap().put("rightRotateStop", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.remove(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);                
                //movement();            
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false), "Shoot");
        getActionMap().put("Shoot", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.add(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);                
                //movement();            
            }
        });

        getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true), "stopShoting");
        getActionMap().put("stopShoting", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                keysPressed.remove(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);                
                //movement();            
            }
        });
    }

    public void movement() {
        //System.out.println("player is at " + playerX +" " +playerY);
        int moveDistance = 4;

        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
            // Move forward
            playerX += moveDistance * Math.sin(rotationAngle);
            playerY -= moveDistance * Math.cos(rotationAngle);
        }

        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
            // Move backward
            playerX -= moveDistance * Math.sin(rotationAngle);
            playerY += moveDistance * Math.cos(rotationAngle);
        }

        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
            rotationAngle -= Math.toRadians(2); 
        }
        
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
            // Rotate left
            rotationAngle += Math.toRadians(2); 
        }

        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)) {
            playerShot.add(shoot());
            //shoot();

            //Shot shot = new Shot();
            //shot.collision(playerX,playerY);
            // Rotate right
        }
       // System.out.println(keysPressed);
    }

    public Shot shoot() {
        return new Shot(playerX + 6, playerY - 10,rotationAngle);
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);


        Rectangle player = new Rectangle(playerX, playerY, 15, 50);

        
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        AffineTransform oldTransform = g2d.getTransform(); // Save the current transform


        AffineTransform rotationTransform = new AffineTransform();
        rotationTransform.rotate(rotationAngle, playerX + player.getWidth() / 2, playerY + player.getHeight() / 2);
        g2d.setTransform(rotationTransform);
        g2d.fill(player);

        //g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        //g2d.fillRect(playerX+6, playerY-10, 5, 5);

        g2d.setTransform(oldTransform); // Restore the original transform

        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        g2d.fillRect(playerX+6, playerY-10, 5, 5);


        
    }
}
```

Shot class

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Shot extends JComponent {
    int shotX;
    int shotY;
    private double rotationAngle; // Angle in radians
    Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    
    public Shot(int shotX,int shotY,double rotationAngle) {
        this.shotX = shotX;
        this.shotY = shotY;
        this.rotationAngle = rotationAngle;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.setColor(Color.red);


        Rectangle shot = new Rectangle(shotX, shotY, 5, 5);

        
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        AffineTransform oldTransform = g2d.getTransform(); // Save the current transform


        AffineTransform rotationTransform = new AffineTransform();
        rotationTransform.rotate(rotationAngle, shotX + shot.getWidth() / 2, shotY + shot.getHeight() / 2);

        g2d.setTransform(rotationTransform);
        g2d.fill(shot);
        g2d.setTransform(oldTransform); // Restore the original transform
        
    }

    public  void collision(){

        shotX += 4 * Math.sin(rotationAngle);
        shotY -= 4 * Math.cos(rotationAngle);

        
      /*   if ((shotX <= -5)|| (shotX >= (int)(size.getWidth() + 5)) || (shotY  <= -5 || shotY >= (int)(size.getHeight() + 5))){
            System.out.println("aaaa");      
        } */
            //shotX += 2;
           // shotY -= 2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not related to your question but, a painting method should only paint the current state of the component, not change the state. The "remove" logic should NOT be in the pantComponent() method. That logic should be in the "movement" method.

Comment: @camickr You are correct I have not gotten to that part yet one issue at the time. right now I cannot figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

I copied your code into my IDE and ran it.

You have a ship (player) that can rotate, move forward and backward, and can shoot a laser beam.  The up arrow key moves the ship forward, the down arrow key moves the ship backward, the left arrow key rotates the ship counterclockwise, the right arrow key rotates the ship clockwise, and the space bar shoots a laser beam.  Holding the space bar makes the laser beam longer.

The ship has no momentum.  It only moves for as long as you are holding down one or more of the arrow keys.

So far, so good.  Here's what it looks like when I start the application and shoot a couple of lasers

[image]

In my testing, I found that I could drive the ship off the screen.  I'm not sure what game you're trying to emulate, since you didn't say.

All four of your classes are extensions of a Java Swing component.  That is not the way to create a complex game.  You will run into problems, as you've already discovered.

@camickr commented about your painting method.  Organizing your code into classes and methods helps you to isolate problems when debugging your code.

## Explanation

When I create a Swing GUI, I use the [model-view-controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (MVC) pattern.  This pattern allows me to separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

In Java Swing, the application model is made up of one or more plain Java getter/setter classes.  The application view is made up of Swing components.  Thye application controller is made up of one or more actions or listeners.

The application model holds the state of the game.

The application view shows the state of the game.  Period.  Nothing else.

The application controllers modify the application model and update or repaint the view.

### Model

I created three model classes, `GameModel`, `Ship`, and `Shot`.

The `GameModel` class is a plain Java getter/setter class that holds an instance of `Ship` and a `List` of instances of `Shot`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GameModel {

    private final Dimension drawingPanelSize;
    
    private final List<Shot> shots;

    private final Ship ship;

    public GameModel() {
        this.drawingPanelSize = new Dimension(400, 400);
        Point2D p = new Point2D.Double(drawingPanelSize.width / 2,
                drawingPanelSize.height / 2);
        this.ship = new Ship(p, 0.0, Color.BLUE);
        this.shots = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    public void addShot(Shot shot) {
        this.shots.add(shot);
    }
    
    public void removeShot(Shot shot) {
        this.shots.remove(shot);
    }

    public Dimension getDrawingPanelSize() {
        return drawingPanelSize;
    }

    public Ship getShip() {
        return ship;
    }

    public List<Shot> getShots() {
        return shots;
    }

}
```

The `Ship` class is a plain Java getter/setter class that holds the position, direction, and velocity of a ship.  This class also draws an image of a ship.  I made the image a triangle, but you can modify the code to make the ship any combination of shapes you want.

Every Java class extends `Object` and can implement a `toString` method for display or debugging.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Ship {

    private final BufferedImage image;

    /**
     * The direction in radians. Zero is north. Positive values rotate
     * clockwise. Negative values rotate counterclockwise.  The velocity
     * is pixels per frame.
     */
    private double direction, velocity;

    private Point2D location;

    public Ship(Point2D location, double degrees, Color color) {
        this.location = location;
        this.direction = Math.toRadians(degrees);
        this.velocity = 0.0;
        this.image = createShipImage(color);
    }

    private BufferedImage createShipImage(Color color) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(25, 40,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        Polygon p = new Polygon();
        p.addPoint(width / 2, 0);
        p.addPoint(0, height);
        p.addPoint(width, height);

        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillPolygon(p);

        g2d.dispose();
        
        return image;
    }
    
    public void moveShip(Dimension drawingPanelSize) {
        double dx = velocity * Math.sin(direction);
        double dy = velocity * Math.cos(direction);
        double x = location.getX() + dx;
        double y = location.getY() - dy;
        x = Math.max(0.0, x);
        x = Math.min(drawingPanelSize.width, x);
        y = Math.max(0.0, y);
        y = Math.min(drawingPanelSize.height, y);
        location.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public double getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void incrementDirection(double degrees) {
        this.direction += Math.toRadians(degrees);
    }

    public void setVelocity(double velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    public Point2D getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("The ship is located at ");
        String display = String.format("%.2f", location.getX());
        builder.append(display);
        builder.append(", ");
        display = String.format("%.2f", location.getY());
        builder.append(display);
        builder.append(" and facing ");
        double angle = Math.toDegrees(direction);
        display = String.format("%.1f", angle);
        builder.append(display);
        builder.append(" degrees");

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

The `Shot` class is a plain Java getter/setter class that holds the position, direction, and velocity of a shot.  This class also draws an image of a shot.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Shot {

    private final BufferedImage image;

    /**
     * The direction in radians. Zero is north. Positive values rotate
     * clockwise. Negative values rotate counterclockwise. The velocity is
     * pixels per frame.
     */
    private double direction, velocity;

    private Point2D location;

    public Shot(Point2D location, double direction, Color color) {
        this.location = location;
        this.direction = direction;
        this.velocity = 5.0;
        this.image = createShotImage(color);
    }

    private BufferedImage createShotImage(Color color) {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage((int) velocity, (int) velocity,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(color);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g2d.dispose();

        return image;
    }

    public boolean moveShot(Dimension drawingPanelSize) {
        double dx = velocity * Math.sin(direction);
        double dy = velocity * Math.cos(direction);
        double x = location.getX() + dx;
        double y = location.getY() - dy;

        if (x < 0.0 || x > drawingPanelSize.width) {
            return false;
        }
        if (y < 0.0 || y > drawingPanelSize.height) {
            return false;
        }

        location.setLocation(x, y);
        return true;
    }

    public double getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public Point2D getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public BufferedImage getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("The shot is located at ");
        String display = String.format("%.2f", location.getX());
        builder.append(display);
        builder.append(", ");
        display = String.format("%.2f", location.getY());
        builder.append(display);
        builder.append(" and facing ");
        double angle = Math.toDegrees(direction);
        display = String.format("%.1f", angle);
        builder.append(display);
        builder.append(" degrees");

        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

### View

I created a `JFrame and a drawing` JPanel`.  Because I created a model, the view is much simpler.

Rather than rotating all sorts of Swing components, I created a `BufferedImage` of the ship and each shot.  That way, I could write one rotating method in the drawing `JPanel` and use it for all the images.

Here's the `Game` class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game implements Runnable {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Game());
    }
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private final GameKeyBindings gameKeyBindings;
    
    private final GameModel model;
    
    public Game() {
        this.model = new GameModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
        this.gameKeyBindings = new GameKeyBindings(drawingPanel);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new GameListener(this, model));
        timer.start();
    }

    public GameKeyBindings getGameKeyBindings() {
        return gameKeyBindings;
    }
    
    public Dimension getDrawingPanelSize() {
        return drawingPanel.getSize();
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
}
```

Here's the `DrawingPanel` class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final GameModel model;

    public DrawingPanel(GameModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.setPreferredSize(model.getDrawingPanelSize());
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        Ship ship = model.getShip();
        BufferedImage image = ship.getImage();
        Point2D p = ship.getLocation();
        double rotation = ship.getDirection();

        drawRotatedImage(g2d, image, p, rotation);
        
        for (Shot shot : model.getShots()) {
            image = shot.getImage();
            p = shot.getLocation();
            rotation = shot.getDirection();
            
            drawRotatedImage(g2d, image, p, rotation);
        }
    }

    private void drawRotatedImage(Graphics2D g2d, BufferedImage image,
            Point2D p, double rotation) {
        BufferedImage rotatedImage = rotateImage(image, rotation);
        int x = (int) Math.round(p.getX()) - rotatedImage.getWidth() / 2;
        int y = (int) Math.round(p.getY()) - rotatedImage.getHeight() / 2;

        g2d.drawImage(rotatedImage, x, y, this);
    }

    /**
     * <p>
     * This method will rotate an image on its center point.
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * First, the image is copied to an image large enough to hold the rotated
     * image at any angle. Then, the copied image is rotated.
     * </p>
     * 
     * @param image    - The image to be rotated.
     * @param rotation - The rotation angle in radians. A positive value rotates
     *                 the image clockwise. A negative value rotates the image
     *                 counterclockwise.
     * @return The rotated image
     */
    private BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage image, double rotation) {
        double newWidthD = getNewImageWidth(image);
        double halfWidthD = newWidthD / 2.0;
        int newWidthI = (int) newWidthD;

        BufferedImage newImage = translateImage(image, newWidthI);
        BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage(newWidthI, newWidthI,
                image.getType());
        AffineTransform tx = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(rotation,
                halfWidthD, halfWidthD);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx,
                AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        op.filter(newImage, outputImage);

        return outputImage;
    }

    /**
     * This method calculates the width of the new image. Basically, calculate
     * the hypotenuse of the width and height of the image.
     * 
     * @param image - The original image
     * @return The width and height of the square that can hold the image
     *         rotated at any angle.
     */
    private double getNewImageWidth(BufferedImage image) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        double newWidth = width * width + height * height;
        newWidth = Math.ceil(Math.pow(newWidth, 0.5));

        return newWidth;
    }

    /**
     * This method copies the image to a new image. The original image is placed
     * in the center of the new image. The rest of the image is filled with
     * transparent pixels.
     * 
     * @param image    - The original image.
     * @param newWidth - the width and height of the new image.
     * @return The translated image
     */
    private BufferedImage translateImage(BufferedImage image, int newWidth) {
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newWidth,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) newImage.getGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, newWidth, newWidth);
        int x = (newWidth - image.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (newWidth - image.getHeight()) / 2;
        g2d.drawImage(image, x, y, null);
        g2d.dispose();

        return newImage;
    }

}
```

I separated the key bindings into a separate class, mainly to help organize the code.  I created two private `Action` classes that I could reuse.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class GameKeyBindings {

    private final Set<Integer> keysPressed;

    public GameKeyBindings(JPanel panel) {
        this.keysPressed = new HashSet<>();
        defineKeyBindings(panel);
    }

    private void defineKeyBindings(JPanel panel) {
        InputMap inputMap = panel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = panel.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, false),
                "moveForward");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, true),
                "forwardStop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, false),
                "moveBack");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, true),
                "backwardsStop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false),
                "rotateLeft");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true),
                "leftRotateStop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false),
                "rotateRight");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true),
                "rightRotateStop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, false),
                "shoot");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, 0, true),
                "stopShooting");

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, false),
                "moveForward");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0, true),
                "forwardStop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, false),
                "moveBack");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0, true),
                "backwardsStop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, false),
                "rotateLeft");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, 0, true),
                "leftRotateStop");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, false),
                "rotateRight");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_D, 0, true),
                "rightRotateStop");

        actionMap.put("moveForward", new KeyAdditionAction(KeyEvent.VK_UP));
        actionMap.put("forwardStop", new KeyRemovalAction(KeyEvent.VK_UP));
        actionMap.put("moveBack", new KeyAdditionAction(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN));
        actionMap.put("backwardsStop", new KeyRemovalAction(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN));
        actionMap.put("rotateLeft", new KeyAdditionAction(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT));
        actionMap.put("leftRotateStop", new KeyRemovalAction(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT));
        actionMap.put("rotateRight", new KeyAdditionAction(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT));
        actionMap.put("rightRotateStop", new KeyRemovalAction(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT));
        actionMap.put("shoot", new KeyAdditionAction(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE));
        actionMap.put("stopShooting", new KeyRemovalAction(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE));
    }

    public Set<Integer> getKeysPressed() {
        return keysPressed;
    }

    private class KeyAdditionAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final int keyEvent;

        public KeyAdditionAction(int keyEvent) {
            this.keyEvent = keyEvent;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Integer value = Integer.valueOf(keyEvent);
            keysPressed.add(value);
        }
    }

    private class KeyRemovalAction extends AbstractAction {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private final int keyEvent;

        public KeyRemovalAction(int keyEvent) {
            this.keyEvent = keyEvent;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Integer value = Integer.valueOf(keyEvent);
            keysPressed.remove(value);
        }
    }

}
```

### Controller

I created one separate controller class.  I alrady mentioned the two private `Action` classes for key bindings.

The `GameListener` class is the game loop.  Move the ship, move the shots, and repaint the drawing `JPanel`.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class GameListener implements ActionListener {

    private final Game view;

    private final GameModel model;

    public GameListener(Game view, GameModel model) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        double velocity = 4.0;
        double degreesRotated = 2.0;
        GameKeyBindings gameKeyBindings = view.getGameKeyBindings();
        Set<Integer> keysPressed = gameKeyBindings.getKeysPressed();
        Ship ship = model.getShip();

        model.getShip().setVelocity(0.0);
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) {
            ship.setVelocity(velocity);
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
            ship.setVelocity(-velocity);
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)) {
            ship.incrementDirection(-degreesRotated);
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)) {
            ship.incrementDirection(degreesRotated);
        }
        if (keysPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)) {
//          System.out.println(ship);
            Point2D s = ship.getLocation();
            Point2D p = new Point2D.Double(s.getX(), s.getY());
            Shot shot = new Shot(p, ship.getDirection(), Color.RED);
            model.addShot(shot);
        }

        Dimension drawingPanelSize = view.getDrawingPanelSize();
        ship.moveShip(drawingPanelSize);

        List<Shot> shots = model.getShots();
        for (int index = shots.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            Shot shot = shots.get(index);
//          System.out.println(shot);
            boolean valid = shot.moveShot(drawingPanelSize);
            if (!valid) {
                model.removeShot(shot);
            }
        }

        view.repaint();
    }

}
```

## GUI

Here's a picture of the revised GUI.  I made it a lot smaller so it fits in this answer better.

In Windows, you can click on a box in the upper right corner to make the GUI use the whole display.

[image]

Comment: Oh wow I did not think I was gonna get a reply on this. But wow you really did put effort into it. Since you managed to solve the problem I know have  a lot of code to study and learn from thank you.